# Specflow: pass a IWebElement trough step argument transformations

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I want to do something like this (note the IWebDriver instead of the typical string)

```
[Given(@"I select ""(.*)"" option")]
    public void GivenInISelectOption(IWebDriver p0)
    {
        MainMenuPage.SelectOption(p0);     
    }
```

Being the MainMenuClass like this:

```
class MainMenuPage
{
    //spans
    public static IWebElement SetupMenu
    { get { return Configuration.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[@id='Setup_navItem']")); } }

    public static void SelectOption (IWebElement element)
    {
        element.Click();
    }
}
```

The case of use should be like this:

```
And I select "SetupMenu" option
```

QUESTION: Is it possible to use step argument transformations yo make the step definition accept a IWebElement instead of the string?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if its possible or not, but I wouldn't advise it regardless. However here is a way you could get around your problem:

```
[Given(@"I select ""(.*)"" option")]
public void GivenInISelectOption(string p0)
{
    if(p0.Equals("SetupMenu"){
        MainMenuPage.SelectOption(MainMenuPage.SetupMenu);
    }     
}
```

This way you can still call the option you need from the stepdef

Another simpler way is to do this:

```
[Given(@"I select ""(.*)"" option")]
public void GivenInISelectOption(string p0)
{
    if(p0.Equals("SetupMenu"){
        MainMenuPage.SetupMenu.Click();
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible, assuming that in some other step you have already defined what page you are working with. I'm going to assume that you have placed the current page in the ScenarioContext with the key 'CurrentPage'.

I think you have soemthing wrong in your question as you want `IWebElement` not `IWebDriver` to be passed into your method.

What I would do is write a `[StepArgumentTransformation]` method something like this (untested, assume pseudo code but basically gets the property via reflection and then gets its value).

```
[StepArgumentTransformation]
public IWebElement TransformToWebElementOnCurrentPage(string elementName)
{
    object currentPage = ScenarioContext.Get("CurrentPage");
    //get the property of the current page with the given name
    var props = currentPage.GetType().GetProperties();
    return (IWebElement) props.First(x=>x.Name==elementName).GetValue(null);
}
```

if you haven't set the current page into some object then you could instead loop round all of your page objects looking for the property, but I think this will cause issues in the future and you would be better just setting the current page somewhere.